# Ggplot2 centre y axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm sure there's a simple solution but I have looked around and can't find anything.

Essentially I just want to flip the `y-axis` title horizontally then center it along the `y-axis`. I have managed to flip it but I can't seem to find an argument that centers it along the axis.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(tidyverse)

iris %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, you were almost there. Under the argument `element_text`, you can edit the arguments `vjust` and `hjust` for vertical and horizontal positioning.

```
require(tidyverse)

iris %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]